# I need guidance on creating a sql query code

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the table 'Clients' with (firstname, lastname, phone, street, city, state, zip)

and I am trying to create an MySQL query for finding how many clients live in each state with the result only showing states with more than 5 clients. Any help please?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `HAVING`.

Answer (score 2):

it is as simple as grouping them with state column and count each group then filter to only show state with count > 5:

```
select state , count(*) clientcount
from 'Clients' 
group by state
having count(*) > 5
```